# How to print output neatly in R?

Tags: r

I am currently learning R for which I am using the Johns Hopkins COVID-19 Dataset ([The link to the dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/11-08-2020.csv)

I want to print the top 5 `Province_State` with the most number of cases

for which I wrote this code

```
i<-1
for (case in top5){
  idx=match((case),dataset[,"Confirmed"])
  print(c(i,"\t",dataset[,"Province_State"][idx],"\t",case)
  i<-i+1
  }
```

I want it to be printed like this(Displaying dummy results just for reference)

```
1 "Region1" 1000
2 "Region2" 900
3 "Region3" 800
4 "Region4" 700
5 "Region5" 600
```

But my output gets printed as

```
1      "Region1"    1000
2 "Region2"  900
3 "Region3"   800
4   "Region4" 700
5   "Region5"    600
```

Comment: There are other functions to print vectors, `help('cat')` or `help('sprintf')`, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the output will look better if you lean on dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Province_State) %>%
  summarize(Confirmed = sum(Confirmed)) %>%
  arrange(desc(Confirmed))
    
df <- df[1:5,]
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
l <- list()
i<-1
for (case in top5){
  idx=match((case),dataset[,"Confirmed"])
  l[[i]] <- paste(i,dataset[,"Province_State"][idx],case, sep = " ")
  i<-i+1
}
cat(paste(unlist(l), sep = " ", collapse = "\t"))
```

Edit: I didn't test this